C strlen on char array
I'm new to programming, so I was practicing with C. Then I ran to a problem with my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "Hello";
    printf("Length of a: %lu\n", strlen(a));

    char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    printf("Length of b: %lu\n", strlen(b));
}

I am expecting to get:
Length of a: 5
Length of b: 5

Instead, I'm getting:
Length of a: 5
Length of b: 10

I have tried different strings, but every time, b has double the length of a
Why is the length of b is double of a?

b is not a string — it has no null terminator.  Therefore, it may not be passed to strlen() or any other function expecting a null-terminated string.  What you're seeing is "undefined behaviour" — any result is possible.  It's likely that what's happening is that b is stored just before a in memory and, therefore, strlen() calculates the length of a and the length of b, but that's far from guaranteed.  You most certainly can't rely on it.

char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};

The correct format for printing the result of strlen() is %zu (the z is the type indicator for size_t values).

@JonathanLeffler What may not be obvious to C beginners is that string literals like "Hello" have an implicit extra character appended, the zero byte, even though it is not explicitly written. That is, "" has an array length (and a sizeof result) of 1, the zero byte, even though it seems empty and the strlen result is 0.

This is undefined behavior because the b array has no null terminator. The strlen function is searching for that so it knows when to stop counting.
So, what happens is it runs off the end of the array and keeps going until the OS segfaults or you encounter a byte with the value zero in memory that's not part of the array.
To better understand the differences between your two arrays, read more here: Array Initialization
Regarding your specific question:

Why is the length of b is double of a?

This is not guaranteed at all. It is happening to you by pure chance. To understand better, you'd need to look at the generated assembly for your program. It could be a result of how the compiler is arranging other parts of your program in memory, or it could just be that you're seeing a pattern that doesn't exist.

So strlen(b) returns the last value of length before it segfaults?

@hasaanE No, strlen() returns the number of characters until it hits a '\0'. Since b has no '\0', the function continues outside the vector and hopefully finds it somewhere else, because anything bad happens.

No, strlen(b) reads through every byte of your array, doesn't find a null byte, and continues searching memory that follows the array until it finds one. If you're "lucky" there might be a null byte immediately after, meaning you'll have a very nasty bug because you won't notice it's broken.

@hasaanE No, a segmentation fault is an irregular, abrupt end of the program wherever it just happens to be executing; the caller's code is never reached again. If strlen returns, there was a zero byte early enough in memory that it was still accessible by the program so that no segmentation fault happened.

@paddy so it's complete luck like you said

Yes, more formally, this is called undefined behavior. Anything can happen. You cannot rely on correct operation of code that has undefined behavior, even if it seems to work. Regarding the segfault, that might happen if you read into a section of memory that is protected by the OS. That's more likely to happen if your array is located at the end of a page/segment.

It is not “pure chance.” Do not use that as a proxy for undefined behavior. Sometimes people need to investigate bugs, including malicious people exploiting bugs for nefarious purposes. If undefined behaviors were pure chance, it would be impossible to reason about them, to reproduce them even partially, and to otherwise diagnose and investigate them. Almost all behaviors stemming from bugs involve various things that are not pure chance—operating system memory management, data patterns left in memory by earlier software, compiler behavior, and more…

… Learning about these is useful and helps diagnose and fix errors. They are important and contribute to understanding overall computer behavior.  Saying they are pure chance is advising people to be ignorant.

C strings are char array terminated by the *null character

char a[] = "Hello"; initializes the char array a with string literal "Hello" which is {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; initializes the array with the exact characters listed in the initializer. It does not contain terminating null character and b does not contain a valid C string. When you pass this array to any string function you invoke Undefined Behaviour


I have tried different strings, but every time, b has double the
length of a Why is the length of b is double of a?

It is not as the behaviour of the call to strlen is undefined. You can receive any value, the program my crash or may get the correct result if by accident you will have zero just past the last element of array.
You also have another UB in your code as you use wrong printf format as strlen returns size_t The correct format is %zu.  printf("Length of a: %zu\n", strlen(a));

Your code is wrong. As you may know, C strings are null terminated array of chars, so when you write:
char a[] = "Hello";

the compiler knows the array size in compile time. In this case, 6. because it implicitly appends a '\0' to your string.
But in
char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

the compiler won't add the '\0' to the array. So you must manually add it to your array.
So this is the correct form of your code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "Hello";
    printf("Length of a: %lu\n", strlen(a));

    char b[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    printf("Length of b: %lu\n", strlen(b));

    /* compiler assume 0 for return value, but it is better
       to add return to your non-void functions. */
    return 0;
}

The result is:
Length of a: 5
Length of b: 5

